# Is it right to write "Thank you for your personal interest"?

Tags: phrase-request

I would like to express my gratitude for giving attention personally to some matter (he doesn't delegate!).

Is it right to write (in an email):

> #### Thank you for your personal interest?

Do native speakers use some others idiomatic expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little difficult to tell from your example what 'giving attention personally' means, but to cover both possibilities -

If the person you are replying to simply expressed interest in the matter at hand, the stock response usually is

**Thank you for your interest in this matter.**

If the person you are replying to has actually done something to correct/improve/interracted in some way with the matter at hand, a better response would be

**Thank you for your attention to this matter.**

as it implies an action of some sort from the person you are writing to.

Edit:
Your edit to your original post makes things somewhat clearer. A more fitting response for your situation would be along the lines of

**Thank you for attending to this matter personally.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I've improved my question adding a specification as a result of your answer: I meant the second possibility you highlighted, I want to thank him because he doesn't delegate to someone else. 
I think that, with regard to my question, your second phrase is already too general and doesn't stress the reason why I am grateful.

Comment: I've amended my answer accordingly. Given the situation you describe, something along the lines of "Thank you for attending to this matter personally." might be more fitting.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, but it seems too formal because of the "attending to" verb. I am also looking for a less formal sentence.

Comment: "Thank you for taking care of this personally" would be a less formal way of saying this.

Comment: Thank you! This is very close to what I was looking for! :)